# Can I use/include HTML partials, client-side, using EJS (or similar)?

Tags: javascript, html, partial, ejs

On the client, I would like to be able to do something similar to the below :

**public_html/index.html**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="ejs-or-similar.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="some-partial"></div>
      <script>
         var partialHTML = Magic.render('partials/some-partial.ejs');
         document.getElementById('some-partial').innerHTML = partialHTML;
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**public_html/partials/some-partial.ejs**

```
<div>Hi, I come from a different file!</div>
```

Is it possible ?

If yes, which EJS file/documentation should I use :

```
http://ejs.co/
http://www.embeddedjs.com/
https://github.com/tj/ejs
```

*Please note that I'm not interested in a discussion as to whether client-side templating is a good or bad idea, etc... Just saving everyone some precious time in advance :-)*

Comment: If you're targeting new enough browsers, you could try using a <template> tag and grabbing its .innerHTML to feed into EJS. I haven't tried this, but it should let you include templates in your code without making a hideous mess. The more backwards-compatible approach is to use a `<script type="text/plain">` tag in the same way, but that's more likely to confuse your editors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJS will allow you to render out templates on the client side, but you will need to provide it the template string directly and not just the file path as it does not support XHR.

ejs.co (github.com/mde/ejs) is version 2 of EJS and is more actively supported.

Comment: So in other words I can't really use partials on the client. Providing the template string instead sounds really ugly, more like a hack if anything. I can't imagine writing the whole HTML of my partial as a string between quotes. I could do that without using EJS to be honest, with a simple Js function I could write. Anyway, thanks for clarifying!